# Fields in RDS Postgres are not showing in Appflow when doing the fields mapping

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-appflow

I created an Appflow and use RDS Postgres as destination. When doing the fields mapping after setting set the connection to DB, only 4 fields can be selected from RDS Postgres, but there are 20 fields created in that table.

I tried to create  and use the different tables but still got this same situation. What possible issue this could be?

What possible issue this could be?